# Get a custom field value saved in Order items meta in a hooked function

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I am able to add, validate, display on cart and checkout page a custom field on the Product Page.Please can someone tell me how can I retrieve the custom field values using **woocommerce_order_status_completed** hook?

I want to send an additional email including the custom field data after the confirmation email is sent to the user

```
static function sendCustomData($order_id) {
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    $items = $order->get_items();

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $product_id = $item['product_id'];

        $Id = get_post_meta($product_id, '_wpws_ID', true);
        $first_name = $order->get_billing_first_name();
        $billing_email = $order->get_billing_email();


        if (empty($Id))
        continue;

        $mail = new CustomMails();
        $mail->SendMailtoReaderOnWCOrderComplete($first_name, $billing_email, $Id);
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed','sendCustomData');
```

> Saving custom order meta value

```
public static function tshirt_order_meta_handler( $item_id, $values, $cart_item_key ) {
    if( isset( $values['name_on_tshirt'] ) ) {
        wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, "name_on_tshirt", $values['name_on_tshirt'] );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order_item', 'tshirt_order_meta_handler', 1, 3 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get **`"name_on_tshirt"`** custom field, you need to get the order Item ID and you need to use wc_get_order_item_meta() function this way:

```
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item) {
    ## HERE ==> Get your custom field value
    $name_on_tshirt wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, "name_on_tshirt", true );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change `if (empty($Id))` .. to `if (empty($wbnId))`

Comment: I understand, that was a typo but not working yet. I have updated my question