# Get product variation description to display on order items in woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66286871/add-description-field-contents-for-variable-product-to-woocommerce-completed), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48390818/get-the-selected-variation-attributes-from-orders-in-woocommerce-3) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42471822/woocommerce-display-product-variation-description-on-order-page) (and many others), I still can't map each product variation description to the right order item (I'm usingproduct variations). This code displays both descriptions on both order items. How do I iterate over the ids so that the descriptions are not duplicated for each order item?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'add_variation_description_to_order_item', 20, 4 );
function add_variation_description_to_order_item( $item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text ) {

// for each product ordered
 foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item  ) {
     
            $product = $item->get_product();
            $description = $product->get_description();
                  
            echo '<p>' . $description . '</p>';
    }
    
}
```

As you can see here descriptions are duplicated:[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. It turns out I had to use the $order_item instead of $item in the loop, no clue why though, and of course echo outside the loop:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'add_variation_description_to_order_item', 20, 4 );
function add_variation_description_to_order_item( $item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text ) {

// Loop though order "line items"
 foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $order_item ) {
        $product = $item->get_product();
        $description = $product->get_description();       
         
 }
    if ( ! empty( $description ) ) {
    echo '<br> <p>' . $description . '</p>';
    }
}
```