# How to show attributes in wc_get_orders custom loop?

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I have to show the name of product and product attributes like that:

```
Product name
Color: Green
Size: XS.
```

My code of the loop now is like that. For each status, that's the example of 'completed', but with other statuses loops are the same

```
    <section class="order">
<?php 
$orders = wc_get_orders( array(
  'numberposts' => -1,  
   'orderby' => 'date',
   'order' => 'DESC',  
   'customer_id' => get_current_user_id(),
   'status' => array('completed'),
) );


//* Loop through each WC_Order object
foreach( $orders as $order ){?>
    <div class="order-wrapper product d-flex col-12">
        <?php 
        $order_data = $order->get_data(); // The Order data
        $order_id = $order_data['id'];
        $order_currency = $order_data['currency'];
        $order_status = $order_data['status'];        
         ?>

        <div class="order-number">#<?php echo  $order_id;?></div>         
        <div class="order-inner">
            <div class="order-inner-top">
                <?php    
                foreach ($order->get_items() as $key => $lineItem) {
                $product_id = $lineItem['product_id'];
                $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
                $name = $lineItem->get_name(); 
                $item_meta_data = $lineItem->get_meta_data();             
                ?>
                <div class="order-inner-top-inner">
                    <div class="order-slider-inner"> 
                        <div class="order-inner-left">
                            <div class="order-image">
                                <?php echo $product->get_image(['322', '304']);?>                                    
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="order-inner-right">
                            <div class="order-info-item order-info-item-name">
                                <?php echo $name; ?>
                           </div>
                           <div class="order-info-item order-info-item ">
                                <span class="order-price"><?php echo $lineItem['total'] . $order_currency?></span>
                           </div>
                           <div class="order-item-quantity"><?php esc_html_e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' )?>: <?php echo $lineItem['qty']?></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php }  ?>          
            </div>          
          
          <div class="order-inner-bottom">
               <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <button class="order-total"><?php echo get_theme_mod('orders_total_button');?></button> 
              </div>
              <div class="totals-toggle">
                  <div class="order-info-item bottom"> <span> <?php esc_html_e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' )?>:</span><span class="order-total-price"> <?php echo $order->get_total() . '  ' . $order_currency; ?></span></div>       
                  <div class="order-info-item bottom"> <span> <?php esc_html_e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' )?>:</span> <?php echo  $order->get_item_count(); ?></div>         
                  <div class="order-info-item bottom"> <span><?php esc_html_e( 'Status', 'woocommerce' )?>:</span> <?php
               
                  if( 'completed'== $order->get_status() ) {
                     echo _x( 'Completed', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' );                     
                    }     
                   ?></div>
                <div class="order-info-item bottom"> <span><?php esc_html_e( 'Order Date', 'woocommerce' )?></span> <?php 
                    if( $date_created = $order->get_date_created() ){
                        // Display the localized formatted date
                         $formated_date_created = $date_created->date_i18n('d.m.Y ');
                         echo  $formated_date_created;
                    }                   

                   ?></div>
                   <div class="order-info-item bottom"> <span><?php echo get_theme_mod('delivery_date_text')?>: </span> 
                   <?php 
                        // The orders date
                         $date_created = $order->get_date_created();
                         $date_created =  $date_created->date('d.m.Y');
                        // The order date + 5 days
                        $delivery_date = date_i18n( 'd.m.Y', strtotime( $date_created . ' +21 days' ));                       
                        echo $delivery_date;
                    ?>
                     </div>
                </div>
          </div>        

        </div>       
 </div> 
<?php  }?>

</section>
```

The name in that way is showing like Name,Green,XS - as one string.
If to change $name = $lineItem->get_name(); to $name = $product->get_name(); it's showing only product name.
I tried to use

```
$name = $product->get_name();
 $colormeta = $lineItem->get_meta( 'pa_color', true );
  $sizemeta = $lineItem->get_meta( 'pa_size', true ); 
echo $name . ' <br>';
echo 'Color:'. ' ' .  $colormeta;
```

But then attributes are showed not like Green,not by name, they show like green-en, green-ru = by slug, not by name.I use hyyyan polylang.
I've found the decision for the cart page, that I needed, I need the same for orders

```
function custom_product_variation_title($should_include_attributes, $product){    
        $should_include_attributes = false;
        return $should_include_attributes;  
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_title_include_attributes', 'custom_product_variation_title', 10, 2 );
```

How can I show the attributes in the order loop like
Product name
Color: Green
Size: XS
correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you should access your order items:

```
foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {

    $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
    
    $product = $item->get_product();
    
    $product_title = $product->get_title();
    $output = array();
    $output[] .= '<ul>';
      $output[] .= '<li>'.$product_title.'</li>';

    if( $product->is_type('variation') ){
        // Get the variation attributes
        $variation_attributes = $product->get_variation_attributes();
        // Loop through each selected attributes
        foreach($variation_attributes as $attribute_taxonomy => $term_slug ){
           // Get product attribute name or taxonomy
           $taxonomy = str_replace('attribute_', '', $attribute_taxonomy );
           // The label name from the product attribute
           $attribute_name = wc_attribute_label( $taxonomy, $product );
           // The term name (or value) from this attribute
           if( taxonomy_exists($taxonomy) ) {
               $output[] .= '<li>'.$attribute_name.': '.get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomy )->name.'</li>';
           } else {
                $output[] .= '<li>'.$attribute_name.': '.$term_slug.'</li>'; // For custom product attributes
           }
        }
   }
    $output[] .= '</ul>';

}
echo implode('',$output);
```

Credits also to - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48391504/13378498

Comment: it's similar to what I need, but it shows all available sizes and colors of the product, not only chosen in this order. is there a way to show only chosen ones?

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: I replace my foreach ($order->get_items() as $key => $lineItem) {.... with that, and don't see anything. If I delete  if( $product->is_type('variation') ){, I see Color: and Size:, but not their values, don't know why

Comment: Is it variation product ?

Comment: all of them are