# Getting custom field value after order completed woocommerce hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have added custom field named 'pin_type' to all products.

The field has string value "single" or "multi" etc..
Im using 'woocommerce_order_status_completed' hook in function.php to do some stuff.

I just cant get the custom 'pin_type' value to show anything. I used phpMyadmin to search for pin_item in wp database and every products pin_item seems to be there in wp_postmeta table under 'meta_key' column and the values are under 'meta_value' column.

How do I get the value based on the product in the order?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'pincodeactions', 10, 1);

function pincodeactions( $order_id ) {
     $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
     $order_id  = $order->get_id();
     $price = $order->get_total();
     $billing_email = $order->get_billing_email();
     $paid_date = date('Y-m-d h:m:s', strtotime($order->get_date_paid()));
     //$pin_type = $order->get_meta('pin_type'); //not working: Returns empty string
     $pin_type = get_post_meta( $this->order->get_id(), 'pin_type', true ); //ERROR: Using $this when not in object context
     echo pin_type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:
[Get a custom field value saved in Order items meta in a hooked function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44985868/get-a-custom-field-value-saved-in-order-items-meta-in-a-hooked-function?rq=1)

My working code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'pincodeactions', 10, 1);

function pincodeactions( $order_id ) {
     $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
     $order_id  = $order->get_id();
     $price = $order->get_total();
     $billing_email = $order->get_billing_email();
     $paid_date = date('Y-m-d h:m:s', strtotime($order->get_date_paid()));
     
     //Get pin type
     $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
     $items = $order->get_items();
     
     foreach ($items as $item) {
        $product_id = $item['product_id'];
        $pin_type = get_post_meta($product_id, 'pin_type', true);
        
        if (empty($pin_type)){
            $pin_type = 'test';
        }
     }
```